# Could not find function mutate_if

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the function `mutate_if` under `dplyr()` package to convert all the character columns to factor columns. I am aware of alternate approaches for this transfromation, but I am curious to see how `mutate_if` works. I tried the following command:

```
df <-df %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)
```

But I am geting a message, :

> `could not find function mutate_if`

I reinstalled `dplyr()` but still I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Did you load `dplyr`? `library(dplyr)`?

Comment: @bouncyball, Yes I did invoke the dplyr library and retried but no change.I am getting the same error. Any guesses/ advice will help. thanx

Comment: If it helps, I can see this message:

Comment: 'The following objects are masked from ‘package:plyr’:

    arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise,
    summarize'

Comment: Which version of `dplyr` are you using?

Comment: The plyr and dplyr packages conflict with each other. (And this is especially true when plyr function names mask dplyr function names.) You may get better success here if you restart R and load plyr  before dplyr.

Comment: Please add `sessionInfo()` output.

Answer (score 2):

When I was having this problem, I also got the error message "there is no package called 'pillar'" while loading the dplyr package. (Re-installing dplyr didn't seem to install pillar.) Installing the pillar package allowed things to work again.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <-df %>% dplyr::mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)
```

Try like this. when I faced the same error I used the mutate function like this.

Answer (score -3):

There is no more mutate_if function. You could use this one which is really long if you would not be able to extract names of variables which are from type of character:

```
dt1 <- dt1 %>% mutate_each_(funs(as.factor),names(which (sapply(dt1, class) == 'character',arr.ind = TRUE)))
```

If you have list of factor variables lets say in "varlist" object, you can use this one:

```
dt1 <- dt1 %>% mutate_each_(funs(as.factor),varlist)
```

Comment: There is a `mutate_if` listed in the index of the version of dplyr that is up-to-date per CRAN.

Comment: I checked the most recent pdf of CRAN there was noting.

Comment: Your powers of searching seem week, my friend. Pages 49 and 66 are listed in the Index and the string `mutate_if` appears 6 times in the version 0.5.0 document: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf